# Use custom branded domain and own SSL certificate

Tags: tls

I want to give my users the possibility to use my web service with their own custom branded domain, but I want to let them the responsability of generating and handling the SSL certificate for the HTTPS communications, is it possible?

Just to explain me better, I offer a service which is available at https://myservice.com and I would like to give my users the possibility to bring their own custom branded domain so that my service can be available from https://myusercustombrandeddomain.com.
Of course if HTTPS was not present, the problem was simply solved telling my user to just create a CNAME DNS record on their DNS server pointing to myservice.com, however with HTTPS it doesn't suffice because on the browser the communication would result insecure.
Surely I could create on my own a new SSL certificate, one for each custom branded domain, however I didn't want to take this responsibility and I wanted to let them the possibility to use their own SSL certificate. In addition I don't want them to upload their certificate and I don't want to host their private keys.

Is this something possible? Is there available any technology or protocol to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at LetsEncrypt? It automates the process for you ...

Comment: What you describe is basically what every hosting provider provides, i.e. it is a long solved thing with many implementations. You either let the users upload a certificate they bought or you let users automatically create the certificate for the domains they host with you using Let's Encrypt or similar.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich both the solutions you mentioned require me to host their SSL certificate on my server, the point here is that I don't want to host their SSL certificate or at least their private keys

Comment: So, let me see if I have this correct: 1. you host the service 2. you want others to fork the service on your servers with different domains. 3. You want them to use TLS with their own certificates 4. But you don't want to host the certificates for the domains and services you host. Can I ask why having the certificates on your server is an issue? You host everything else of value or sensitivity. Why balk at hosting the key that protects what you are serving?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich does a CDN do this sort of thing the OP wants?

Comment: @schroeder To be honest it's not a problem, I'm evaluating all possibilities. Apart from the certificate itself, I want to give my users the possibility to check the private key on their systems

Comment: I think it would be weird, TBH. As a customer, I'd expect you to host the certificate. Not to make it my responsibility.

Comment: @schroeder Searching online I found this interesting solution https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/keyless-ssl/

Comment: @zer0uno: *"the point here is that I don't want to host their SSL certificate or at least their private keys"* - that's a new requirement you did not had shown before (only after edit). *"I found this interesting solution cloudflare.com/ssl/keyless-ssl"* -  This approach is an option but there is no easy way to build something like this by your own and it requires support from the customer too. In general - it is strange that you a) want to host the content b)  be responsible for the domain but c) don't like to deal with the certificate which protects content on this domain against sniffing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich pretty clear